# Laptop overheats when left to idle

Tags: windows-8.1, overheating

If I leave my laptop on and allow it to idle it nearly always gets really hot and the fans kick in.

If I then move the mouse around, it cools down again.

I've tried to see if any particular application or service starts up when it's idle but as far as I can tell nothing does.

The strange thing is, if I keep using it, it doesn't overheat. Only when idle.

I have cleaned it out and replaced the thermal paste with no difference.

The laptop was built by PowerPC nearly 5 years ago, but still copes with everything I throw at it.

The processor is an i7-4810MQ.

RAM 32GB

HDD is 1TB 5400RPM - yes I know it's slow but I can't see how a faster one would help this situation

Video is a Geforce GTX980

OS is Windows 8.1 - would it maybe help to upgrade?

Comment: It may be worth leaving a process monitor (and GPU monitor) running and disable screen shutoff when idle. Then watch the CPU/GPU usage to see what is spiking when your machine is left idle.

Comment: I did that. The number 1 contender by far seems to be `Antimalware Service Executable`, followed by `WMI Provider Host` and `Microsoft Common Language Runtime native compiler`. Is there a way to stop the Antimalware Service Executable from starting?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Antimalware+Service+Executable has a few suggestions you could try.

Comment: Just an update, I have taken some of the measures suggested in your comment. Will update when I have a result...